# What terms are equivalent to 'meaning' in Sanskrit, or Buddhist thought?

Tags: untagged

What terms are equivalent to 'meaning' in Sanskrit, or Buddhist thought more generally?

Especially in terms of, how to live a meaningful life, and what is considered meaningful in Buddhist philosophy.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artha

Answer (score 2):

A Pali word [translated as "meaningful"](https://suttacentral.net/search?lang=en) is "[sāttha](https://suttacentral.net/define/s%C4%81ttha?lang=en)" (sa + [attha](https://suttacentral.net/define/attha?lang=en)), which also literally means 'with/having purpose', 'with/having benefit', 'with/having advantage', 'with/having profit'.

This/these words can be found in many suttas, such as below:

> And so, mendicants, this spiritual life is not lived for the sake of
> possessions, honor, and popularity, or for accomplishment in ethics,
> or for accomplishment in immersion, or for knowledge and vision.
> Rather, the **goal [purpose]** (etad**attha**midaṁ), heartwood, and final end of the
> spiritual life is the unshakable freedom of heart.
>
> [MN 29](https://suttacentral.net/mn29/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin)

> Furthermore, a mendicant is very learned, remembering and keeping what they’ve learned. These teachings are good in the beginning, good in the middle and good in the end, **meaningful (sātthaṁ)** and well-phrased, describing a spiritual practice that’s entirely full and pure. They are very learned in such teachings, remembering them, reinforcing them by recitation, mentally scrutinizing them, and comprehending them theoretically. This too is a quality that serves as protector.
>
> [AN 10.17](https://suttacentral.net/an10.17/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin)

> This venerable brings up a deep and **meaningful** saying (**attha**padaṁ) that is peaceful, sublime, beyond the scope of logic, subtle, comprehensible to the astute.
>
> [AN 4.192](https://suttacentral.net/an4.192/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=false&script=latin)

Therefore, when we read the Teachings above, what is meaningful is:

- ethics, concentration (immersion) & wisdom (knowledge & vision) leading to freedom of mind
- qualities that serve as a protector
- that which is peaceful & leads to peacefulness